# If statement causes a crash in the iOS device but not in the Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, if-statement, ios-simulator

So, this code runs properly, without causing any crashes in the iOS simulator. However, on my iOS device (my iPhone), this causes a crash! Can anyone guess why? The logs haven't helped anywhere.

```
NSInteger loops = 1;
char character = '.';
if ([futureTr rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",character]].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSArray *dotsArray = [futureTr componentsSeparatedByString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",character]];
    loops = [dotsArray count];
    if ([[dotsArray objectAtIndex:loops-1] isEqualToString:@""] || [dotsArray objectAtIndex:loops-1] == nil) {
        loops--;
    }
}
```

And I know that it's this statement that causes trouble, because I comment it out and the app just works fine! What can be going on?

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: And `NSArray` can't store a `nil` value so there is no need to check for it.

Comment: This would crash if `[dotsArray count]` for some reason returned 0, because then `loops` would be 0, and `loops-1` would be -1, which is never a valid array index.

Comment: @rmaddy True, thanks, but removing it doesn't make any difference... Unfortunately, all I can find is: "Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11" and that it's a SIGSEGV, BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I didn't say that would solve the problem, just pointing out that it wasn't needed. Anyway, sounds like a memory problem. Are you using ARC or MRC? How is `futureTr` set? Which line causes the error? The `if` line or one of the lines after it?

Comment: @Gavin Yes, but this is why the first if statement exists. To ensure that at least 1 dot exists and that count isn't 0. So if you're in this if, the count can't be 0

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, I tested the code on ARC and it works fine. However, my project is using MRC and it crashes on MRC. futureTr is a variable that can be used throughout the class. I'll put retain in its definition and I'll let you know. This might solve the issue :)

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry my bad. futureTr is an extern NSString of a different class that is imported. I've used it elsewhere, so that variable should be ok

Comment: Most likely you are overreleasing `futureTr`.

Comment: Try turning on zombies and see if it helps. Look in the log for reference to using a zombie object.

Comment: @rmaddy Unfortunately, I ensured it's retained, by doing this in the viewDidLoad : `keepTheFuture = [[[NSString alloc] init] retain]; keepTheFuture = futureTr;`And using keepTheFuture in the statement

Comment: That does nothing to retain `futureTr`. In fact, that causes a memory leak. Try `NSString *keepTheFuture = [futureTr retain];`.

Comment: what is `futureTr`. what it have?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes that made the trick. Thanks a lot :) Pose it as an answer and I'll approve it!

Comment: @FahimParkar futureTr is an extern NSString that is imported in this class. It is obviously a class variable, but it was released at some point as it seems. However, rmaddy's answer made the trick, so thanks for asking!

Comment: @isklikas I posted the answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, the problem is that `futureTr` is being released at some point and this code then attempts to use the now deallocated pointer resulting in the "BAD_ACCESS" exception.

Proper memory management of this variable will alleviate the problem.